# How to search for phrases in solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I have a question about dismax.

I have this query:

```
/itas?q=privacy%20policy&debugQuery=true&wt=xml&indent=on&pf=title^99&ps=2&mm=2&ps=2&qs=2
```

I get this reseponse with the debugQuery turned on

```
 <lst name="debug">
    <str name="rawquerystring">privacy policy</str>
    <str name="querystring">privacy policy</str>
    <str name="parsedquery">
+((DisjunctionMaxQuery((text:privacy)~0.01) DisjunctionMaxQuery((text:polici)~0.01))~2) DisjunctionMaxQuery((title:"privacy polici"~2^99.0)~0.01)
    </str>
    <str name="parsedquery_toString">
+(((text:privacy)~0.01 (text:polici)~0.01)~2) (title:"privacy polici"~2^99.0)~0.01
    </str>


    <lst name="explain">
        <str name="http://blah.com/">
0.0 = (MATCH) sum of: 0.0 = (MATCH) sum of: 0.0 = (MATCH) weight(text:privacy in 0), product of: 7.610095E-4 = queryWeight(text:privacy), product of: 1.0009153 = idf(docFreq=1091, maxDocs=1093) 7.603136E-4 = queryNorm 0.0 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(text:privacy in 0), product of: 1.4142135 = tf(termFreq(text:privacy)=2) 1.0009153 = idf(docFreq=1091, maxDocs=1093) 0.0 = fieldNorm(field=text, doc=0) 0.0 = (MATCH) weight(text:polici in 0), product of: 7.6379965E-4 = queryWeight(text:polici), product of: 1.004585 = idf(docFreq=1087, maxDocs=1093) 7.603136E-4 = queryNorm 0.0 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(text:polici in 0), product of: 1.0 = tf(termFreq(text:polici)=1) 1.004585 = idf(docFreq=1087, maxDocs=1093) 0.0 = fieldNorm(field=text, doc=0)
        </str>
```

I see that in the parsedquery_toString section that title is queried "privacy polici", but why doesn't that same string get considered in the response?  Everything is split up into "privacy" and "policy"

Answer (score 0):

then you must search for `q="privacy polici"`

Comment: I understand I can do that, but I don't want to, I want it to take the pf boosting into account, but somehow, it doesn't appear to be doing so.

Comment: Given your query specifies the pf parameter, you do not need the proximity query explicitly expressed, you are correct.

Comment: with edismax, there are several instances where if you don't give the phrase query explicitly, it won't be added, for example https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2988

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have any documents that match that phrase query? It looks correct to me. That phrase won't show up in the explanation for documents that are matched by single word phrases, but that do not match the phrase. The score for a document will only include matching terms \ phrases.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the search is done only on the text field and not the title field

The thing to watch for when using pf (Phrase field) is that it only affect boosting of results, but doesn't affect the matching.

So if you are not getting results boosting by the title field, look back at the schema, and make sure the title field is (indexed = true), maybe that is the reason.

Maybe you could get more help, if you put the schema and sample of your response you're getting